# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ñz\endcsname\@safe@activesfalse39 (U+C66)

Tags: errors, input-encodings, compilation-error

I'm having the following error taking the first page of my latex document:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ñz\endcsname@safe@activesfalse39 (U+C66) not set up for use with LaTeX
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>
> Your command was ignored.
>
> Type I   to replace it with another command, or  to continue without it.

I do not know where the error is coming from. I have not found the same error anywhere. I have tried several things but, since I do not understand what this error is pointing to, I also do not know how to summarized properly what I did to solve this problem.

Any idea?

This is my preamble:

```
% Preamble

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\parindent=4em
\setlength{\parskip}{2em}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\linespread{1.6}

%packages

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[right=70pt,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{Pág. \thepage}
\fancyhead[]{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\quoteruleskip}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! The preamble is, unfortunately, not sufficient to diagnose the problem. You should try to reproduce the issue with a short piece of code.

Comment: Thank you. Well, the issue is that I am not sure what it refer to with this error. I would try to summarize it next time